# Forcing screen to quit when it receives sighup

Tags: python, linux, signals, fabric, gnu-screen

I know that screen is not supposed to quit when it receives sighup, but turns out backgrounding apps in fab (a Python library) is not allowed, so I have to use something like screen. But I now want the "backgrounded" process to exit when fabric exits. I can't figure out how to tell fabric to send a sigkill to this process instead of sighup or to make screen respect the sighup signal.

Comment: you can use fabric to run `'start your_thing'` (that starts your thing but does not wait for it to finish e.g., it may start a daemon) and run `'stop your_thing'` later.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Can you please elaborate? Or point me to relevant documentation?

Comment: you can run a process that starts a daemon process and returns immediately. Later you can run a process that sends the daemon a signal (asynchronously) to exit. `start/stop` in my example are `initctl` commands but you could use any command that works in your case.